# XmlSerializer aborts reading after reader.Read()

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Why the XmlSerializer aborts reading when using his reader?
[image]

Sample XML [- here -](http://t78.ch/i?q=39).

Download sample project [- here -](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=kZYaCY7ZGDPuyKDXaAm7kNLqzXOTRuJ9mpzX&discountcode=fvQaqKRsy5JVbsgrrqwgqRZV).

When using the `XmlSerializer` the class can be serialized and deserialized.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MainItem));
using (var reader = new StreamReader(SettingFile.FullName))
{
    var deserializedObject = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    ret = (MainItem)deserializedObject;
}
```

**Model to serialize**

```
public class MainItem
{
    public List<Child1> Child1{ get; set; }
}
```

In the `ConnectionModel` I have one custom class where I grab the XmlReader from XmlSerializer to deserialize on custom way. This is done by implementing interface `IXmlSerializable` to my class.

```
public XmlSchema GetSchema()
{
    return null;
}


public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{

    reader.Read(); // <-- as soon as I comment this out, the serializer will finish proper!
}



public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement(nameof(PropertyInfo.Name));
    writer.WriteString(Value.Name);
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    writer.WriteStartElement(nameof(PropertyInfo.PropertyType));
    writer.WriteString(Value.PropertyType.Name);
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    writer.WriteStartElement(XML_PropertyTypeFullName);
    writer.WriteString(Value.PropertyType.FullName);
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    writer.WriteStartElement(nameof(PropertyInfo.CanRead));
    writer.WriteString(Value.CanRead.ToString());
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    writer.WriteStartElement(nameof(PropertyInfo.CanWrite));
    writer.WriteString(Value.CanWrite.ToString());
    writer.WriteEndElement();

}
```

`reader.Read()` will **not throw any exception** at all. And it reads the values correctly into the model but for testing, I commented all out, except this one line of `reader.Read()`. It shows `?XmlTextReader(reader).LineNumber` in debug Window with middle of the file, not EOF. If `reader.Read()`is in use (not commented out), it will read one single item instead of the next items.

Is there anything to focus on when using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` when using `IXmlSerializable` combined?

Comment: The most likely reason is that you did not [implement `IXmlSerializable` correctly](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly).  If you don't follow the instructions precisely, the `XmlReader` will be wrongly positioned and subsequent elements will get skipped, or deserialization will abort.  Need a [mcve] including the XML to be sure.  For instance, you might have forgotten to consume the end element if there was one.

Comment: For examples of implementing `IXmlSerializable` correctly, see [Proper way to implement IXmlSerializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279534/3744182)  and [Deserializing collection of types implementing IXmlSerializable runs forever](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42671036/3744182).    I prefer using `xmlReader.ReadSubtree()` or `XNode.ReadFrom(reader)` inside `ReadXml()` as shown in the second link as using either makes it much less likely to leave the `XmlReader` wrongly positioned.

Comment: The XML is validated. You can see it here: http://t78.ch/i?q=39

Comment: A complete VisualStudio sample project was added to download in project description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading your project, I was able to create something approaching a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OvPQ6J.  While no exception is thrown, large chunks of the XML file are skipped causing the `<ChildItems>` collection to be missing entries.

The problem is that your `ReadXml()` is not advancing the `XmlReader` past the end of the corresponding element as required in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.readxml.aspx#Anchor_1) (emphasis added):

> The ReadXml method must reconstitute your object using the information that was written by the [`WriteXml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.writexml.aspx) method.
>
> When this method is called, the reader is positioned on the start tag that wraps the information for your type. That is, directly on the start tag that indicates the beginning of a serialized object. When this method returns, it must have read the entire element from beginning to end, including all of its contents. Unlike the `WriteXml` method, the framework does not handle the wrapper element automatically. Your implementation must do so. **Failing to observe these positioning rules may cause code to generate unexpected runtime exceptions or corrupt data.**

Thus unexpected, random exceptions are a documented possible consequence of incorrectly implementing `ReadXml()`.  For more, see *[Proper way to implement IXmlSerializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279534/3744182)* and *[How to Implement IXmlSerializable Correctly](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly)*.

Since it is so easy to make this mistake, you can systematically avoid it by either bracketing your XML reading logic in a call to [`ReadSubtree()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree.aspx) or loading the entire XML into memory with [`XNode.ReadFrom()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom.aspx), e.g. using one of the following two base classes:

```
public abstract class StreamingXmlSerializableBase : IXmlSerializable
{
    // Populate the object with the XmlReader returned by ReadSubtree
    protected abstract void Populate(XmlReader reader);

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        // Consume all child nodes of the current element using ReadSubtree()
        using (var subReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
        {
            subReader.MoveToContent();
            Populate(subReader);
        }
        reader.Read(); // Consume the end element itself.
    }   

    public abstract void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer);
}

public abstract class XmlSerializableBase : IXmlSerializable
{
    // Populate the object with an XElement loaded from the XmlReader for the current node
    protected abstract void Populate(XElement element);

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        var element = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(reader);
        Populate(element);
    }   

    public abstract void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer);
}
```

And here's a fixed version of your `SerializableClass` which uses `XmlSerializableBase`:

```
public class SerializableClass : XmlSerializableBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = "Test title";
    public string Description { get; set; } = "Super description";
    public int Number { get; set; } = (int)(DateTime.Now.Ticks % 99);

    protected override void Populate(XElement element)
    {
        this.Title = (string)element.Element(nameof(this.Title));
        this.Description = (string)element.Element(nameof(this.Description));
        // Leave Number unchanged if not present in the XML
        this.Number = (int?)element.Element(nameof(this.Number)) ?? this.Number;  
    }

    public override void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(nameof(this.Title));
        writer.WriteString(this.Title);
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.WriteStartElement(nameof(this.Description));
        writer.WriteString(this.Description);
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.WriteStartElement(nameof(this.Number));
        // Do not use ToString() as it is locale-dependent.  
        // Instead use XmlConvert.ToString(), or just writer.WriteValue
        writer.WriteValue(this.Number);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Notes:

- In your original code you write the integer `Number` to the XML as a string using `ToString()`:

  ```
  writer.WriteString(this.Number.ToString());
  ```

  This can cause problems as the return of `ToString()` can be locale-dependent.  Instead use [`XmlConvert.ToString(Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9e9xxkb.aspx) or just [`XmlWriter.WriteValue(Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30zk4z5w.aspx).
- `XmlReader.ReadSubtree()`leaves the `XmlReader` positioned **on** the `EndElement` node of the element being read, while `XNode.ReadFrom()` leaves the reader positioned **immediately after** the `EndElement` node of the element being read.  This accounts for the extra call to `Read()` in `StreamingXmlSerializableBase.ReadXml()`.
- Code that manually reads XML using `XmlReader` should always be unit-tested with both formatted and unformatted XML, because certain bugs will only arise with one or the other.  (See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18282052/3744182) and [this one also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19165632/3744182) for examples of such.)

Sample working .Net fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/s9OJOQ.

Comment: Thanks for all your usable effort. I saw, main change is only to use `XNode.ReadFrom(reader)` instead of `read.Read()`. In that case, the reader points to `NodeType = EndElement` of `Child` when leaving `ReadXml(XmlReader reader)`. By manually moving to this tag by using `reader.Read()` 11 times, it has same effect and it works. Even if your structure of classes is better. Great work!